# Accessing variable address in VS Code - cpp DAP (debug adapter protocol) programmatically/any other way to access the address of the variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am currently building a VS Code extension and unable to access the address of the variables via a request to vscode-cpp tools dap.

Here's what I tried:

```js
for (const variable of variables) {
    // vscode.window.showInformationMessage(variable.name + " " + variable.value+" "+dscope);
    panel.webview.postMessage({
        command: 'updatecontent',
        pid: "name",
        varattr: dscope,
        name: variable.name,
        value: variable.value,
        valueattr: variable.name + dscope,
        nextinstr: nextinstr,
        lineno: lineno,
    });
    //For pointer handling------------------------------------------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    //  const tempo= session.customRequest("evaluate", { expression: "&"+ variable, frameId: currstack.frmano,context: "repl"});
    //  vscode.window.showInformationMessage(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+JSON.stringify(tempo));

    if (activedebugsession) {
        // Your code to handle the active debug session
        const expression = "&" + variable;
        try {
            const result = await activedebugsession.customRequest('evaluate', { expression, frameId: 1, context: 'hover' });
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + JSON.stringify(result));
        } catch (err) {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Error in evaluation: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
        // ...
    } else {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("No active debug session");
    }
} // Note: Updating the HTML here may not be necessary, as you're updating it in response to the webview message
```

I was expecting it to return me the address of all variables but it didn't return anything instead of an error:

> Error in evaluation: {"name":"CodeExpectedError","message":"Cannot evaluate expression on the specified stack frame."}